How to split tunnel particular IP addresses on Tunnelblick (mac)?
I have company supplied .ovpn file, once I connect to vpn via Tunnelblick and that .ovpn file, one of the crucial websites for me is not reachable, I get access denied from their cloudflare. Is it possible to somehow make requests to that website to not go through vpn? What I tried so far (example) was to:

nslookup google.com

Server:     1.0.0.1
Address:    1.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.16.46


Edit my .ovpn file and add this line:

route 172.217.16.46 255.255.255.255 net_gateway


Restart vpn and use this edited .ovpn file

Sadly it didn't work, I still get access denied.
